# Send form data without hidden inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

Up to this point, I've been using the following method to send form data to a PHP file (through Ajax). The problem with this is that the "hidden" inputs can still be viewed in the source code to reveal data that I don't want to be seen by users:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input name="user_field">
    <input name="user_id_field" hidden>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JQuery/Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/verification.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $user = $_POST['user_field'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id_field'];

    // verification code and echo back to document
?>
```

My question is, how do most websites send form data without using hidden inputs? I've heard using sessions works, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks.

Comment: If the data is sent to the server in anyway, it can be changed. Learn about sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: sensible data should not be available client side

Comment: I agree with AWOlff, you should never ever send sensible data to client because it can be viewed and manipulated. If you can't work with sessions (for example because you need some _easy_ load balancing) then you may try (but I would avoid if possible) to encrypt that data.

Comment: @A.Wolff Which is why I'm asking this question...

Comment: @Bagwell to make my previous comment more clear, sensible datas are never send to server because it is never available client side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the users initial login, establish a session and user id for remainder of session:

**router.php**

```
   session_start();
   /* once user has authenticated */
   $_SESSION['user_id_field'] = $userid;
```

**subsequentpages.php**

```
   session_start();
   /* assign user id to local variable */
   $userid = $_SESSION['user_id_field'];
   ... do your stuff
```

Each page instantiates a session and assigns a local variable that is only available to that page.

Comment: And these are hidden an uneditable by the user?

Comment: Its not impossible, but unlikely.  A malicious script could try and capture the session id then modify data.  But as far as the the form is concerned, the user ID wouldn't be anywhere in the script output (unless you print it).

Comment: Sessions are server-side assigned values which cannot be viewed in any way **unless** you specifically echo the values in PHP. Or, that a user has actually hacked into the server. Other than that, using sessions is safe, but cookies are not which is a `different animal` altogether. @Bagwell

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible, because any data that is sent to browser is accessible to the user. The only way to do what you want is to encrypt data.

Here is code I use for this:

```
define('CRYPT_KEY', 'some_secret_key');

function dataEncrypt($data) {
    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, CRYPT_KEY, $data, 'ecb');
    $base64 = base64_encode($crypt);
    return $base64;
}

function dataDecrypt($data) {
    $crypt = base64_decode($data);
    $str = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, CRYPT_KEY, $crypt, 'ecb'), "\0\4");
    return $str;
}
```

`CRYPT_KEY` is your own random string

**UPDATE:**

To use `mcrypt_encrypt` and `mcrypt_decrypt` you should install a package `php5-mcrypt`. On Ubuntu-like systems it can be done by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```